# Octoprint Javascript API Socket issues

Tags: javascript, sockets, printing, octoprint

I'm using the Octoprint Javascript API (http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/jsclientlib/index.html) to make a dashboard to view multiple printers at once for a school project. This will run on a web server that is completely separate from my OctoPi's. I have been using the REST API to get data, but was never able to get the sockets to work properly. I found out about the Javascript API and have gotten that to work for basic requests, but want to connect with sockets to get updated data on printer status. Very simply, I have added the following lines to my HTML and have been doing some testing:

```
<script src="sockjs.min.js"></script> (Downloaded a copy of sockjs from their github page yesterday)
<script src="packed-client.js"></script> (Downloaded this by opening octopi.local and copying the source)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
        <div id="test_area"></div>

        <script>
                OctoPrint.options.baseurl = (my ip here);
                OctoPrint.options.apikey = (api key here);

                OctoPrint.socket.connect();

                OctoPrint.socket.onMessage("*", function(message){
                       document.getElementById('test_area').innerHTML = response;
                });
        </script>
</body>
```

The onMessage handler never even fires. I get this error in Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://(my ip
>   here)/sockjs/info?t=1490302299698. The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of
>   requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
>   withCredentials attribute.

There seems to be an issue with CORS and SockJS.

These are the headers:

```
Request URL:http://(my ip here)/sockjs/info?t=1490302365251
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:(ip here):80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Length:77
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 23 Mar 2017 20:52:45 GMT
Etag:"d88498e8b1e0e1a411f64eb3eb6e219315b36ef4"
Server:TornadoServer/4.0.2
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:session_P80=eyJfaWQiOnsiIGIiOiJNVGRrWm1OalpEZzRZV00xTkRNd1lqZzJOMkpsWkRCbU4yWTFaR1JpTmpZPSJ9fQ.C7W5Xg.DmKIY6AJktPrR8_8Es8wa9iBc10
Host:(ip here)
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36
```

Any ideas how to get this working? This is the most basic setup I could do and it doesn't function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, the issue ended out being that I was running the website directly in the browser (via file:// instead of through a web server), plus small errors that were copied over from my larger example code (response vs message variable names, plus I forgot to copy over the JQuery import that was in my other code). There was also a bug in Octoprint that made subscribing to "*" not work, but according to the developer, there will be a fix in the next version. So, in short, spin up a web server, get the new software when it is released (1.3.3).